# Homeomorphism between $X$ and $X \times {y_0}$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove this.

Injectivity and surjectivity are pretty trivial, but I'm not sure on continuity.

If I take an open set in $X \times {y_0}$ is it true that the inverse of this open set is open since $y_0$ is fixed? If so, how can I formalise this?

Comment: What is your candidate for the homeomorphism? $x \mapsto (x,y_0)$?

Comment: $f : X \to X \times Y; x \mapsto x \times y_0$

Comment: Well. That mapping being continuous is a pretty direct consequence of the definition of the product topology. (Remember that it has something to do with the preimages of projections.)